# magento1.9 console errors

Tags: magento-1.9, console

how can I fix the following errors in the console

```
ReferenceError: Itoris is not defined

eferenceError: Varien is not defined

TypeError: this.each is not a function
```

[image]

thanks

Comment: Disable js-merging first of all to see whether it is related to that

Comment: if i disable js merge iam able to see the file but iam unable to fix the issue